# Обращение к элементу через XPath

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath

Как обратится к элементу через `Xpath`?

Например, есть `Xpath` к диву вида:

```
//*[@id="question-suggestions"]/div/div[4]/div
```

Как изменить у див содержимое, используя Xpath, через javascript?
Интересует именно есть ли какой-нибудь базовый метод или способ обращения к элементу, через XPath, а не создание своей функции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.evaluate("//*[@id='question-suggestions']/div/div[4]/div", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE).singleNodeValue
```

Подробнее можно прочитать, к примеру, [на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript).

Comment: Спасибо, это то что нужно! :)